# Stacked bar graphs in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(aushealth, aes(x=condition, y=Population, fill=year)) +
+ geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

Hoping to have the years side by side, but they appear on top of each other.

```
Condition     Year   Population
Asthma        2001   10.0
Asthma        2017   13.1
Back Issue    2001   7.5
Back Issue    2017   6.3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, please check a guide on how to ask good questions on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how to make good reproducible examples in R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example . It will help you get higher quality answers faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some errors in the code:

```
tt = "Condition Year Population
Asthma 2001 10.0
Asthma 2017 13.1
Back_Issue 2001 7.5
Back_Issue 2017 6.3"

dat <- read.table(text = tt, header = T)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=Condition, y=Population, fill=as.factor(Year))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

`Condition` wasn't with capital C, also use `as.factor` on `Year`. That was the main issue.

[image]